# How to find the index for matched elements in a list in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a list of names and I want to find the indices for names that partially match a pattern. For example, I want to search for "ohn" and find the indices of all names that have "ohn" in them>

Here is what I did:

```
r = re.compile(".*ohn")
Index = []
for idx in range(0,len(Names)):
    if r.match(Names[idx]):
        Index.append(idx)
Index
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The matcher objects come with a `span()` function you can use to get the start and end indices.

Comment: @cs95 The OP is looking for indices of the list of strings, not indices within a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to generate indices for a sequence in a list comprehension instead:

```
[idx for idx, name in enumerate(Names) if r.match(name)]
```